# Emacs installation fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, 20.04, emacs

I am trying to simply do:

```
sudo apt install emacs
```

on Ubuntu 20.04.

The result is that it appears there is an error installing `emacsen-common` in `emacs-gtk` which is ultimately a dependency of all of emacs. The error I am seeing is:

```
Setting up emacs-gtk (1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2) ...
Install emacsen-common for emacs
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs
emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libotf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs-gtk (--configure):
 installed emacs-gtk package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs:
 emacs depends on emacs-gtk (>= 1:26.3) | emacs-lucid (>= 1:26.3) | emacs-nox (>= 1:26.3); however:
  Package emacs-gtk is not configured yet.
  Package emacs-lucid is not installed.
  Package emacs-nox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package emacs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs-gtk
 emacs
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am hoping to get some ideas around how to fix this.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. No idea how to properly install emacs yet, but managed to get `apt` into a normal state by running `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq` for each package with unmet dependencies.

Comment: I managed to fix this by running `sudo apt install --reinstall libotf0 libm17n-0` after purging emacs.. no idea why it works. but it does.

Comment: Nice, that worked for me too.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, I first did `sudo apt purge emacs`.

I then reinstalled libotf0 and libm17n-0, using:

`sudo apt install --reinstall libotf0 libm17n-0`

after that, `sudo apt install emacs` worked as expected.

Comment: Hmm, do you have a PPA for this? For me it errors, `Unable to locate package libotf0`

Answer (score 0):

One can do it also in another way : using snap package through [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/emacs)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where installing emacs-gtk resulted in post-installation script errors, apparently related to elpa-company package. This happened both during upgrade from Kubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04 and running 21.04.

Thanks everyone for good hints, after trying several things, the problem was solved after I purged all emacs* packages:

`sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends emacs emacs-common ...`

installed all emacs* packages except emacs and emacs-gtk using:

`apt-get download <package>`

`sudo dpkg -i --force-depends <package_file>`

installed emacs-gtk as above and finally installing emacs (`sudo apt install emacs`).

Answer (score 0):

This requires `libotf1` not `libotf0`. So do the following:

First `sudo apt purge emacs`.

I then reinstalled libotf1 and libm17n-0, using:

`sudo apt install --reinstall libotf1 libm17n-0`

after that, `sudo apt install emacs` worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to reinstall emacs-gtk

```
sudo apt install --reinstall emacs-gtk
```

Then install emacs again

```
sudo apt install emacs
```

I hope this helps